# How to sort 2 ArrayLists of different types of data in the same order?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an ArrayList of String and an ArrayList of int.

My ArrayList of Strings contains:

```
index : value
-----------------
0     : "Paul"
1     : "Peter"
2     : "Maria"
```

My ArrayList of Integers contians:

```
index : value
-----------------
0     : 2
1     : 0
2     : 1
```

Suppose I sort my int array using

```
Collections.sort(myArrayOfint);
```

The result should be 0 at index 0, 1 at index 1, and 2 at at index 2 right?

What I want to do is sort my String array taking in consideration my int Array's new order, so for example "Paul" would go to index 1, "Peter" to index 2, and "Maria" to index 0. The order would be swapped same as my int array.

How can I do this, is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have separate ArrayLists instead of a single one containing Objects that have a String and an int?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have an int associated to a String on which you want to sort and did not use that int in the first place as index when adding your Strings to the list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create class with the properties and use different `Comparator`s that compares based on different properties:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    //getter/setter
}

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
});


Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getId().compareTo(p2.getId());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

My feeling is that you have an array of ints and an array of Strings, but you should have a single array of `Person` objects, a `Person` having a field `ID` of type `int`, and a field `name` of type `String`. Sort your persons by ID, and both the names and IDs will of course be sorted in the same order.

Use Objects. That's what OOP is all about.

Comment: Can you give a short example please? It seems to be the best solution. How to separate a String and an int in an ArrayList index, and how to sort it by int value?

Comment: There is an example in βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ's answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not sort `myArrayOfint`: it defines the permutation according to which you are sorting your array of strings. The simplest way to do it is with a temporary array, like this:

```
String tmp[] = new String[myArrayOfint.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != myArrayOfint.length ; i++) {
    tmp[i] = myArrayOfStrings[myArrayOfint[i]];
}
myArrayOfStrings = tmp;
```

This works, because

```
myArrayOfStrings[myArrayOfint[0]] = myArrayOfStrings[2] = "Maria"
myArrayOfStrings[myArrayOfint[1]] = myArrayOfStrings[0] = "Paul"
myArrayOfStrings[myArrayOfint[2]] = myArrayOfStrings[1] = "Peter"
```

This problem can be solved without a temporary array as well, but the algorithm is more complex.