# Sort list of string by list of integer

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am new to Java. This problem definitely has been asked here but I am not sure which question. Consider this Java code snippet.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<>();

names.add("John");
names.add("Kate");
names.add("Bob");

ages.add(27);
ages.add(24);
ages.add(32);
```

How to sort `names` by `ages`? That is the new `names` should be `["Kate", "John", "Bob"]`.

Comment: That will be quite tricky. It would be much easier to put them together into dedicated `Person` objects and sort that. Like, much easier. Do proper OOP and group what belongs together...

Comment: You have to make a single container for both **Name** and **Ages**

Comment: Your two lists have no relationship, so you can't.

Comment: Try `IntStream.range(0, ages.size()).boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> ages.get(i))).map(i -> names.get(i)).toList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to populate a hashmap using the names as keys and the ages as values.  Then, sort using this lookup map.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < names.size(); ++i) {
    map.put(names.get(i), ages.get(i));
}
Collections.sort(names, (a, b) -> map.get(a).compareTo(map.get(b)));
```

As some of the other comments and answers have alluded to, you could also create a person class which stores both a name and age in a single logical object.  Then, write a comparator which sorts based on age.

Comment: Pretty much the same solution, using a stream pipeline: `IntStream.range(0, ages.size()).mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i, ages.get(i))).sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).map(p -> names.get(p.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

You have two unrelated lists, you cannot sort one according to the other without specifying how they are linked.

The most straightforward way would be to create a `class Person` to store the name and age, use a single list and sort this list using a `Comparator` on the age.

Answer (score -1):

You can create class with the properties and use different Comparators that compares based on different properties. Then use an ArrayList containing objects of the new class.

See:
[How to sort 2 ArrayLists of different types of data in the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719498/how-to-sort-2-arraylists-of-different-types-of-data-in-the-same-order)

Comment: If you think an answer to another question already answers this question, then you do not need to post a new answer saying that. We close questions as duplicates in this situation.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know. Next time I'll close it 